# C++ implementation of DHT

Tags: c++, cross-platform, dht

I am looking for opensource implementations of [Kademlia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kademlia) DHT in C/C++. It must be lightweight and crossplatform (win/linux/mac).

It must be able to post information to DHT and retrieve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's wrong with [maidsafe-dht](http://code.google.com/p/maidsafe-dht/) ?

Comment: Thanks! I git-cloned source and it seems very quality and understandable.

Answer (score 5):

[OpenDHT](https://github.com/savoirfairelinux/opendht) is a lightweight Kademlia DHT in C++11. The API is very simple :

```
dht::DhtRunner node;

// Launch a dht node on a new thread, using a
// generated RSA key pair, and listen on port 4222.
node.run(4222, dht::crypto::generateIdentity(), true);

// Join the network through any running node,
// here using a known bootstrap node.
node.bootstrap("bootstrap.jami.net", "4222");

// put some data on the dht
std::vector<uint8_t> some_data(5, 10);
node.put("unique_key", some_data);
```

It supports compiling with LLVM or GCC on OS X, Linux and Windows.

Answer (score 2):

LibTorrent's Kademlia DHT is written in C++ and is well documented.
Here is example code with immutable and mutable get/put operations:  https://github.com/arvidn/libtorrent/blob/master/tools/dht_put.cpp

Answer (score 1):

You could try [bitdht](http://bitdht.sourceforge.net/) used by retroshare.

Comment: too bad its not exactly complete.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a [BitTorrent DHT library](http://www.pps.jussieu.fr/~jch/software/bittorrent/), used by Transmission. It is written in pure C, but it can be easily used from C++.

I am using it in my C++ project. It works well but requires an external cryptographic hash and randomization functions.